# Add checkbox and then click a button to record into firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently working on a web app using firebase where a teacher can reserve rooms in a school. Here is the code so far:

app.js:

```
const roomList = document.querySelector('#room-list');
function renderRoom(doc){
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let buildingNumber = document.createElement('spam');
    let floorNumber = document.createElement('span');
    let roomNumber = document.createElement('span');
    let block = document.createElement('span');
    let firstName = document.createElement('span');
    let lastName = document.createElement('span');
    li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    buildingNumber.textContent = 'Room: ' + doc.data().buildingNumber + '-' + doc.data().floorNumber + doc.data().roomNumber;
    block.textContent = 'Block: ' + doc.data().block;
    firstName.textContent = 'First Name: ' + doc.data().firstName;
    lastName.textContent = 'Last Name: ' + doc.data().lastName;
    li.appendChild(buildingNumber);
    li.appendChild(floorNumber);
    li.appendChild(roomNumber);
    li.appendChild(block);
    li.appendChild(firstName);
    li.appendChild(lastName);
    roomList.appendChild(li); 
}
db.collection('rooms').where('buildingNumber', '==' , '5').where('floorNumber' , '==' , '1').onSnapshot(snapshot =>  {
    let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
    changes.forEach(change => {
        if(change.type == 'added'){
            renderRoom(change.doc);
        } else if (change.type == 'removed'){
            let li = roomList.querySelector('[data-id = ' + change.doc.id + ']');
            roomList.removeChild(li);
        }
    })
})
```

app.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "Styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Select the room:</h1>
        <div class = "content">
        <form id = "add-room-list"></form>
        <ul id = "room-list"></ul>
        </div>
        <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

        <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
            https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->

        <script>
        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyDNB4Ag8hXa_FDEYdWmQ2H_GMVBpWm1-0k",
            authDomain: "internal-assessment-20dd7.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://internal-assessment-20dd7.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "internal-assessment-20dd7",
            storageBucket: "internal-assessment-20dd7.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "905998751828",
            appId: "1:905998751828:web:1d88f0d2f655eb6141f5c1"
        };
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        </script>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This currently displays a room someone enters. I was wondering how you can add a checkbox to the left of each room so you can click on it and then click a button and it would record the selected room into firebase. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get the values from the checkbox into Javascript variables, so you can use them in your Firestore set. Once you have done that, your code to save the values into Firestore should be something like this:

```
// Add a new document in the collection
db.collection("<your_collection>").doc("<your_doc>").set({
    field1: value1
    field2: value2
    ...
})
.then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});
```

This code is untested and doesn't have your collection and documents names, but you should have it in your Javascript like this, after you initialize your connection with Firestore, for you to be able to write on it. Just save your HTML data into variables and change the collection and document names, for you to be able to use it.

In this article - [Adding Data to a Cloud Firestore Database](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/adding-data-to-a-cloud-firestore-database.html) - you can find a full tutorial, on how to save data from HTML into Firestore.

Let me know if the information helped you!